# jQuery Validation plugin failing to fire onblur and also not validating on submission consistently

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I've used this plugin hundreds of times, literally, and never have had an issue like this.. now, when the form is submitted (with fields empty) the error labels show correctly.. yet, when you fill in a field or two correctly, the error for those fields do not go away.. and if you re-submit the form, it DOES submit.. even with fields remaining empty.. and not validated.

I'm running jQuery v1.8.2 and jQuery Validate v1.11.0
The site is running on Twitter bootstrap, hence the highlight, success and errorPlacement functions at the end of the plugin code.

I can provide a link to the dev. environment if you message me and have a potential fix, but would like to check out the live code (this app is not yet launched, and I've just been hired to clean up some things,.. hence dealing with an issue like this :[ )

Any input is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is the JS:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
submitHandler: function() {
    form.submit();
}
});

$('#register').validate({ 
rules: {
    name: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
    },
    lname: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true,
        remote: {
            url: '/setup/verify_username/',
            cache: false
        }
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: '/setup/verify_email/',
            cache: false
        }
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        alphaNumeric: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 250
    },
    password2: {
        required: true,
        alphaNumeric: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 250,
        equalTo: '#password'
    },
    postal_code: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    },
    timezones: {
        required: true
    },
    mp: {
        minlength: 10,
        required: true
    },
    gender: {
        required: true
    },
    dob: {
        required: true,
        date: true
    }
},
messages: {
    name: "Please enter your first name",
    lname: "Please enter your last name",
    username: {
        required: "Please enter a username",
        minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
    }, 
    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
    password: {
        required: "Please provide a password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
    },
    password2: {
        required: "Please provide a password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
        equalTo: "Please enter the same passwords"
    },
    postal_code: "Please enter a valid email address",
    timezones: "Please select a time zone",
    mp: "Please enter a valid mobile number. Only numbers please.",
    gender: "Please select a gender",
    dob: "Please enter a valid Date of Birth in mm/dd/yyyy format."
},
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
},
success: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    $(element).closest('form').find('.valid').removeClass("invalid");
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element){
    error.text( element.closest('.control-group').find('.help-line') );
},
onfocusout: function(element) { 
    $(element).valid();  
}
});
```

I was reluctant to create a jsfiddle example simply due to all the factors that would differ from the live environment, but on the recommendation of @Sparky, here is it (thanks Sparky)
http://jsfiddle.net/DLcLJ/7/

You can see that if you tab through the fields, it correctly informs you that the field is not valid.. yet if you fill in data, it will remain invalid.. and if you submit the form, the field you just entered valid data into, will remain invalid.. meh...

Comment: Passing out a link to one or two people will be of no benefit to future readers.  Please construct a jsFiddle demo for the benefit of everyone.  Please also include the form's HTML.

Comment: Done, see above for info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to point out my observations about the code you've posted.

I see several potential issues including a lot of redundancy and duplication of default functionality...

---

**1)** You forgot to pass the `form` variable into the `submitHandler` callback function...

```
submitHandler: function() {
    form.submit();
}
```

Should be...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
}
```

It's also the default behavior to submit the form when it passes validation so the entire `submitHandler` can be left out of your options and it will not make a difference in this case.  Just let the plugin handle submission as per its default... which is just to allow the `submit` event if the form validates.  No need to write a custom handler function if you're not doing anything else.

---

**2)**  By default the plugin will validate each field "on focus out". So why are you over-riding the default onfocusout callback function with `$(element).valid();`?  As per your title, it's "failing to fire onblur".  So just remove the following, and let the plugin do this as per it's default...

```
onfocusout: function(element) { // <-- remove
    $(element).valid();         // <-- remove
}                               // <-- remove
```

---

**3)**  Your code...

```
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
},
success: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    $(element).closest('form').find('.valid').removeClass("invalid");
},
```

`success` is fired off "to show a valid element".
`unhighlight` is fired "to revert changes made by option `highlight`".

However, `highlight` and `unhighlight` are the complimentary functions, so maybe you want this instead...

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
},
success: function(label) {
    $(label).closest('form').find('.valid').removeClass("invalid");
},
```

---

**4)**  Your code contained an invalid rule. See comments...

```
password: {
    required: true,
    alphaNumeric: true,  // <-- not valid spelling and plugin missing
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 250
},
password2: {
    required: true,      // <-- redundant
    alphaNumeric: true,  // <-- redundant
    minlength: 5,        // <-- redundant
    maxlength: 250,      // <-- redundant
    equalTo: '#password'
},
```

Should be spelled `alphanumeric` and it also requires the [`additional-methods.js` plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js) which was missing.

```
password: {
    required: true,
    alphanumeric: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 250
},
password2: {
    equalTo: '#password'
},
```

---

**Here is the modified version of the OP's jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/RQnWx/**

[See this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) for a detailed explanation of each callback function and option.

Comment: awesome.. thanks for the clarification on the callbacks and the feedback! I've edited the original post to with a jsfiddle link,. please feel free to check it out when you can.. I will update my local code and see how these changes effect it.. thanks!

Comment: @revive, See my edit above... I simply applied my recommended changes and your fiddle seems to work much better.

Comment: Hi Sparky, yes it does behave a little better.. the odd part is: 1) the passwords wont validate, and 2) you can submit the form the second time you click the submit button..even though there are errors.. what would cause that?

Comment: There were a couple changes that I just made, so I've added them to your jsfiddle... namely, I removed the required: true from password2 since making it equalTo: #password does the same.. and I also corrected a class name within the errorPlacement function, here is the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DCb9g/1/

Comment: @revive, you don't need to duplicate the rules for the second password field since it simply must match the first:  http://jsfiddle.net/DCb9g/2/

Comment: @revive, I cannot duplicate your second issue.  It will not submit with errors no matter how many times I click the button.

Comment: ok cool.. so I see the changes to the password fields.. if you try and type in a name, and email address.. then enter anything into the password fields (that matches of couse).. and click submit.. the form will submit even though the other fields are invalid

Comment: @revive, also `alphaNumeric` is not a valid rule in this plugin.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/yaEaF/

Comment: @revive, It's spelled `alphanumeric` without the capital "N", and it requires the `additional-methods.js` plugin... See:  http://jsfiddle.net/RQnWx/

Comment: @Sparky... seriously?? I'd had that in a snippet from a while back.. and it had worked then (I believe!) #facepalm.... thanks for catching that as well

Comment: another interesting development, in Firebug I get this error, when tabbing or entering data into the first password field: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

Comment: if I dont get the above error, I get this error when entering data into the password field: TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined

Comment: @revive, no errors at all here.  Are you sure you're using the latest jsFiddle I fixed?  http://jsfiddle.net/RQnWx/

Comment: Ok, fixed. I copied your code, used it exactly and it's working.. after checking, mine still had the alphanumeric option in there.. thanks @Sparky! Another ? for validation plugin closed, thanks to you!

Comment: Here is the final jsfiddle, for anyone else facing the errors, typos and issues I had: http://jsfiddle.net/yaEaF/1/

Comment: ,. can you answer this here, or should I open a new question: The errors are NOT showing in the correct element. The code I'm using is from another developer that used this function to place the errors within the native Twitter Bootstrap span.help-block .. .. . here or another question ??

Comment: NOTE: It IS adding the correct class to the .control-group, which then correctly shows the span.help-block.. but the content of the help-block are NOT the messages from the Validation plugin, they're hard coded..

Comment: @revive, definitely a new question.  Keep it concise and self-contained as possible.  Please refrain from referring back to this one since it's technically something else.

Comment: @revive, I noticed that myself.  It's pretty tangled... let's start a new one.